# What kinds of caching does SQLite perform on Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, caching, android-sqlite

I would like to know more about what kinds of caching SQLite performs and how Android configures the cache parameters (I read that those can be controlled via pragmas at compile time.) Does anyone have more insight into this, or even rely on SQLite as an effective cache to cache data obtained from the network?

I understand that SQLite caches pages in memory by default. Is there a query cache too, and is there any way to tweak these parameters from an Android client app even?

The only thing I could find is SQLiteDatabase#setMaxSqlCacheSize, but this is only for prepared statements.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Use PRAGMA cache_size=xx to set the page cache. The number is in units of pages, and the default page size is 1024 bytes. This is no different from SQLite on any other platform. You should also take a look at SQLightning, which uses LMDB as its storage engine and requires no cache tuning.

https://gitorious.org/mdb/sqlightning/source/5a70c78cc0c7b9393ff1373905bf1a852cfab3bc: